# Matplotlib: Using "display" coordinates with set_aspect('equal')

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a weird problem with my class (below) which adds tick marks to a plotted Matplotlib line. It seems that when the axes aspect ratio is set to `'equal'`, the plotting in display coordinates gets messed up in the interactive view for the "zoom" functionality. Panning and resizing works fine, as does "Home", at least after initially correcting the display.
There are no problems without equal aspect ratio set.

Here's the class:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import transforms

def get_perp_vec(u1, u2, direction=1):
    """Return the unit vector perpendicular to the vector u2-u1."""

    x1, y1 = u1
    x2, y2 = u2
    vx, vy = x2-x1, y2-y1
    v = np.linalg.norm((vx, vy))
    wx, wy = -vy/v * direction, vx/v * direction
    return wx, wy

class LineTicks:
    def __init__(self, line, idx, **kwargs):
        self.line = line
        self.ticks = []
        self.idx = idx

        self.tick_length = 20
        self.tick_styles = kwargs

        self.ax = line.axes
        self.ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', self.on_change_lims)
        self.ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', self.on_change_lims)
        cid = self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('resize_event',self.on_resize) 
        self.add_ticks(self.ax)

    def add_ticks(self, ax):
        ax.set_autoscale_on(False)  # Otherwise, infinite loop
        # Transform to  display coordinates
        z =ax.transData.transform(np.array(self.line.get_data()).T)
        x, y = zip(*z)

        # Remove existing ticks
        for tick in self.ticks:
            ax.lines.remove(tick)
        # Remove references to the ticks so they can be garbage-collected
        self.ticks = []

        for i in self.idx:
            tx, ty = get_perp_vec((x[i-1], y[i-1]), (x[i], y[i]))
            tx, ty = self.tick_length * tx, self.tick_length * ty
            this_tick, = ax.plot((x[i],x[i]+tx), (y[i],y[i]+ty),
                transform=transforms.IdentityTransform(), **self.tick_styles)
            self.ticks.append(this_tick)

    def on_change_lims(self, ax):
        self.add_ticks(ax)

    def on_resize(self, event):
        self.add_ticks(self.ax)
```

And here's when it doesn't work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, np.pi/40)
x, y = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
circle_line, = ax.plot(x, y)
major_ticks = LineTicks(circle_line, range(0, len(x), 10), color='r', lw=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

And for reference, here's when it does work:

```
x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, np.pi/40)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
circle_line, = ax.plot(x, y)
minor_ticks = LineTicks(circle_line, range(0, len(x), 2), lw=2, color='k')
plt.show()
```

[image]

What am I getting wrong about the way that `set_aspect('equal')` works, and what should I be doing? Or is this a bug in the backend? [Mac OS X, Python 3.3, Matplotlib 1.4.3]

Comment: I just tried on a Windows system using an WinPython distribution (Python 3.4.3.7, Matplotlib 1.5.0) and it works fine. All LineTicks appear inside the circle. This is likely a bug. Have you tried stating figsize and removing 'equal' aspect?

Comment: @armatita Thanks for this -- I'll see if anyone can reproduce on the macosx backend and then file a bug report.